# How to store multiple values in a profile field (specific to each users)?

Tags: 6, users

I have a profile filed called **Amount** corresponding to each users, and I want to store multiple values in the profile field **Amount**. Bu using the custom module, the value of **Amount** is to be inserted on each registration (or it can be inserted any time by a cron program).

For example User **Williams** has Value 100 in his **Amount** field. This is not a single value, it may be

```
Time    Amount
-------+------
Hour 1 :  10
Hour 2 :  30
Hour 3 :  20
Hour 4 :  35
Hour 5 :   5
============
Total  : 100
```

I want to display the total amount and individual amount by exact time.

How to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might be best installing [content profile](http://drupal.org/project/content_profile) as this will allow you to use cck, when creating the profile field **amount** you can set it to unlimited which would allow you to store multiple values in an array for a single field.

The **total** would be another dynamic field which is calculated by adding the values from the **amount** array each time they are changed via a hook

To add the field to a content profile, follow the below steps:

1. Edit the profile content type
2. Go to manage fields
3. Add a new "text field
4. Fill in field details
5. On this page you will see a "number of values" option, choose "unlimited"

You can update content profile fields as below, just put it in a custom module or something:

```
//load current user
global $user;
//find the users content profile
$uid = $user->uid;
$node = content_profile_load(profile,$uid);
$pid = $node->nid;
$node = node_load($pid);
//update the field AMOUNT
$node->field_AMOUNT[0]['value'] = $var1;
$node->field_AMOUNT[1]['value'] = $var2;
//do the same for the TOTAL with calculations
$node->field_TOTAL[0]['value'] = $var1 + $var2;
//save the content profile node
node_save($node);
```

Comment: Thanks, I have installed the **Content Profile** module, and when I create the profile field **Amount**, I couldn't see the **Unlimited** option.  Please explain your words **which would allow you to store multiple values in an array for a single field** in detail.

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: I think some error in your code, that's why I used this one,                                        **`$node = new stdClass();
$node->type = 'profile';
$node->title = 'This is a title';
$node->body = 'This is the body.';
$node->teaser = 'This is the teaser.';
$node->uid = 25;
$node->status = 0;
$node->promote = 1;
$var1 = 1753;
$node->field_amount[0]['value'] = $var1;
node_save($node);`**

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new profile type in "drupal/module/profile.module" that is called "total."

Comment: But this field can store only one value, i want to store multiple values like the table above